# static/css/main.61381647.css from Css Minimizer plugin at parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript

**Describe the bug**
I am learning react,in [fullstackopen](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part3/deploying_app_to_internet#frontend-production-build),I want to build,but failed,I do some thing like [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11930)
for example

```
rm -rf package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

but  i get a new problem

```
npm run build

> note@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.61381647.css from Css Minimizer plugin
    at parse (<anonymous>)
```

**Steps to reproduce**
Issue can be replicated easily via

```
git clone https://github.com/yougongjiang/FullsatckopenPractice.git
cd part2/note
npm install
npm run build
```

**Expected behavior**
I expected npm run build to work without errors.

Comment: Works fine for me. I'm getting this output:

`Creating an optimized production build...`, `Compiled with warnings.` plus some info about Line 20:1 in `src\services\notes.js`, file sizes and info about how to start it.

Comment: I'm using node 16.13.2 and npm 8.4.0

Comment: I'm using node v16.13.0 npm v8.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I Try many ways and upgrade node versions

My node version is 19.0.1

I run successfully builded after install  below package

**npm install --save-dev autoprefixer postcss**

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing your `package-lock.json` and removing the dependency on Css Minimizer, then re-installing it using
`npm install` afterwards. If that doesn't work, remove it again and consider changing the version of css minimizer you're installing.